# Display html content with contenteditable attribute as input

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable, embedding

Is it possible to use contenteditable attribute as a html editor? For example to paste Youtube embeddable code to the div with contenteditable attribute and to be able to watch the video right away.

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    Text or html here…
</div>
```

Maybe any other suggestions how to do it without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bVHHb/1/

Basically just created an apply button which, when clicked, copies the html from the editable div to a different holder div.  The trick is that you need to decode the html since content editable divs encode html tags.

```js
function htmlDecode(input){
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;
    return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

$("#apply").click(function(){
    $("#holder").html(htmlDecode($("#editable").html()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
    Text or html here…
</div>
<button id="apply">apply</button>

<div id="holder"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Actually it seems to work when the input from the editable content is applied back to the editable div. I got the apply function working with the .focusout() function.

[http://jsfiddle.net/erdMe/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/erdMe/3/)

Comment: Yeah, that should work.  Just be aware that if you then re-edit that content odd things may happen.

Comment: Yes! It's pretty unstable. Strange that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried `Text or html <b>here</b>…` and it's just not displaying "here" for me (Chrome).

Comment: This question is ancient at this point, but the code still seems to work just fine for me in chrome.

Comment: Also allows for XSS